# How to add timeout or debouncing in formvalidation - validations will occur after the user enters data into the input field

Tags: javascript, formvalidation-plugin

```
fields: {
            'customer_email': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: _this.settings.transArray.EMAIL_VALIDATION,
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/, // Only Allow dot (.) after @
                        message: _this.settings.transArray.EMAIL_INVALID_CHARACTER_VALIDATION
                    },
```

here i want the timeout or debounces with "regexp" rule for These validations will occur after the user enters data into the 'customer_email' field, and they will trigger error messages if the entered data does not meet the specified criteria.

i want its in formvalidation keyup event